# Problem with Java GUI. Why does it show duplicated components at the beggining and when the size is changed by the user it shows how the GUI should be

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I've been creating a JAVA GUI for create a project, that includes a timer and some other features, using swing and AWT. When I compile the project, it compiles, but the GUI doesn't seem right because some components are shown duplicated on some random places.

[Weird GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKqx8.png)

But when the user changes the size, it shows how it should be. I couldn't figure out what was the error in the code.

[GUI showing how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaDWM.png)

Also, when I press a button that starts the timer, the GUI starts working bad again.

[When I press a button, it work strange again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diBga.png)

I've tried looking for someone with the same problem on internet, but I couldn't find nothing. Also I tried to understand why it is happening, but I can't it. And I try to change some code, but it didn't seem working.

The code for the project is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame implements ActionListener
{
    
    
    //Variables
    
    Temporizador temp = new Temporizador(10);
    int cronometroCreado = 0;
   private JFrame frame;
   private JPanel paneles[];
   private JPanel subPaneles[][] = new JPanel[2][3];;
   final private int filas[] = {1, 1, 1};
   final private int columnas[] = {1, 3, 3};
   private JLabel titulos[] = new JLabel[7];
   private static JProgressBar barraProgreso;
   private JPanel subSubPaneles[][] = new JPanel[2][3];
   private String titulosNombre[] = {"TO-DO", "Tareas", "Cronometro", "Tiempo", "Calendario", "Música", "Trabajado"};
   private Font fuentes[] = {new Font("Papyrus",Font.BOLD  , 50), new Font("Scheherazade", Font.BOLD    , 20)};
   private Color colores[] = {new Color(227, 244, 244), new Color(248, 246, 244), new Color(210, 233, 233), new Color(196, 223, 223), };
   private Color coloresGris[] = {new Color(237, 225, 239), new Color(232, 217  , 226)};

   //Variables de tareas
   private JTextArea tareas;
   private JButton tareasBoton;
   
   //Variables de cronometro
   static private JLabel cronometro;
   private JPanel cronometroPanel;
   private JButton cronometroBoton[] = new JButton[2];
   
   //Variables de tiempo
   private JLabel tiempo[]; //Esta tiene que ser una clase que tenga un wheel moved listener, asi que teoricamente no sería tan asi
   
   //Variables de calendario
   private JButton calendario;
   
   //Variables de musica
   private JLabel musica;
   private JPanel musicaPanel;
   private JButton musicaBoton[];
   
   //Variables de trabajado
   private JLabel trabajado;
   private JButton trabajadoBoton;
   
//Constructor
   public MainFrame()
   {
       frame = creacionJFrame();
       paneles = new JPanel[3];
       
       //Se crean los titulos
       for(int i = 0, bool = 0; i < 7; i++, bool++)
      {
          titulos[i] = creacionTitulos(i, bool);
      }
       titulos[0].setFont(fuentes[0]);
       //Se crean los subSubPaneles
       
       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       {
           for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
           {
               subSubPaneles[i][k] = creacionSubSubPaneles(i, k);
           }
       }
       
       //Se crea las divisiones principales del frame en 3 paneles
       for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           paneles[i] = creacionPaneles(i);
           frame.add(paneles[i]);
       }
       paneles[0].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       
      paneles[0].add(titulos[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
       //Se crean las subdivisiones dentro de los paneles
       for(int i = 0, num = 1; i < 2; i++)
       {
           for (int k = 0; k < columnas[i+1]; k++)
           {
               subPaneles[i][k] = creacionSubPaneles(i, k);
               subPaneles[i][k].add(titulos[num], BorderLayout.NORTH);
               subPaneles[i][k].add(subSubPaneles[i][k], BorderLayout.CENTER);
               paneles[i+1].add(subPaneles[i][k]);
               num++;
           }
       }
       paneles[0].add(creacionBarraProgreso(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
       System.out.println("Hola mundo");
       
       creacionTareas(0, 0);
       creacionCronometro(0,1);
       creacionTiempo(0, 2);
       creacionCalendario(1, 0);
       creacionMusica(1, 1);
       creacionTrabajado(1, 2);
   } //Fin del constructor
   
   //Este método crea el JFrame dandole sus caracteristicas
   private JFrame creacionJFrame()
   {
       frame = new JFrame("Hola mundo");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(400, 700);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
       frame.setBackground(new Color(227, 244, 244));
       frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 700));
       return frame;
   }
   
   //Este método crea los paneles principales dandole sus caracteristicas
   private JPanel creacionPaneles(int num)
   {
       paneles[num] = new JPanel();
       paneles[num].setLayout(new GridLayout(filas[num], columnas[num]));
       paneles[num].setBackground(colores[0]);
       return paneles[num];
   }
   
   //Este método crea las subdivisiones de los paneles principales
   private JPanel creacionSubPaneles(int row, int column)
   {
       subPaneles[row][column] = new JPanel();
       subPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       subPaneles[row][column].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
       return subPaneles[row][column];
   }
   
   //Este metodo crea paneles que estarán dentro de paneles que dividen a los otros paneles. Estan debajo de los titulos de cada "tema"
   private JPanel creacionSubSubPaneles(int row, int column)
   {
       subSubPaneles[row][column] = new JPanel();
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new GridLayout());
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
       return subSubPaneles[row][column];
   }
   
   private JProgressBar creacionBarraProgreso()
   {
       barraProgreso = new JProgressBar(0, 1000);
       barraProgreso.setValue(1000);
       barraProgreso.setStringPainted(true);
       barraProgreso.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(40,40,40, 40));
       barraProgreso.setBackground(colores[0]);
       barraProgreso.setOpaque(true);
       return barraProgreso;
   }
   
   //Este método crea los titulos de los paneles dandole sus respectivos nombres y formatos
   private JLabel creacionTitulos(int num, int bool)
   {
       titulos[num] = new JLabel();
       titulos[num].setText(titulosNombre[num]);
       titulos[num].setVisible(true);
       titulos[num].setFont(fuentes[1]);
       titulos[num].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       titulos[num].setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
       if (bool % 2 ==  0)
       {
           titulos[num].setBackground(coloresGris[0]);
       }
       else{
          titulos[num].setBackground(coloresGris[1]);
       }
       if(num == 0) {titulos[num].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));}
       titulos[num].setOpaque(true);
       return titulos[num];
   }
   
   private void creacionTareas(int row, int column)
   {
       tareas = new JTextArea();
       tareas.setEditable(false);
       tareas.setBackground(colores[1]);
       tareas.setFocusable(false);

       agregarLinea("Tareas para realizar", tareas);
       agregarLinea("T -  Hacer la cama", tareas);
       tareas.setLineWrap(true); //Hace que las lineas se corten y bajen si llegan al border
       tareasBoton = new JButton("+");
       tareasBoton.addActionListener(this);
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(tareas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(tareasBoton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }
   
   private void agregarLinea(String texto, JTextArea campo)
   {
       campo.append("\n" + texto);
   }
   
   //Se crean todos los componentes dentro de la pantalla de cronometro
   private void creacionCronometro(int row, int column)
   {
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
       
       cronometro = new JLabel("Tiempo");
       cronometro.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       cronometro.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       cronometroPanel = new JPanel();
       //cronometroPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2)); //Reemplazarlo por GridBagLayout que permite mayor control !!!!
       
       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       {
           cronometroBoton[i] = new JButton("Boton");
           cronometroBoton[i].addActionListener(this);
           cronometroPanel.add(cronometroBoton[i]);
       }
       
       cronometroBoton[0].setText("Pausar");
       cronometroBoton[1].setText("Abortar");
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(cronometro);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(cronometroPanel);
   }
   
   private void creacionTiempo(int row, int column)
   {
       tiempo  = new JLabel[3];
       
       for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           tiempo[i] = new JLabel("Hola");
           tiempo[i].setBackground(colores[3]);
           tiempo[i].setOpaque(true);
       }
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(new JLabel());
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(tiempo[0]);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(new JLabel());
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(new JLabel());
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(tiempo[1]);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(new JLabel());
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(new JLabel());
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(tiempo[2]);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(new JLabel());
   }
   
   private void creacionCalendario(int row, int column)
   {
       calendario = new JButton("Calendario");
       calendario.addActionListener(this);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(calendario);
   }
   
   private void creacionMusica(int row, int column)
   {
       musica = new JLabel("La música");
       
       musicaPanel = new JPanel();
       
       musicaBoton = new JButton[2];  
       musicaBoton[0] = new JButton("Parar");
       musicaBoton[1]= new JButton("Pasar");
       musicaBoton[0].addActionListener(this);
       musicaBoton[1].addActionListener(this);        
       
       musicaPanel.add(musicaBoton[0]);
       musicaPanel.add(musicaBoton[1]);
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(musica);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(musicaPanel);
   }
   
   private void creacionTrabajado(int row, int column)
   {
       trabajado = new JLabel("Hoy trabajado: ");
       
       trabajadoBoton = new JButton("Trabajo");
       trabajadoBoton.addActionListener(this);
       
       subSubPaneles[row][column].setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(trabajado);
       subSubPaneles[row][column].add(trabajadoBoton);
   }
   //Setters and getters (static)
    public static void setCronometro(String texto)
    {
        cronometro.setText("");
        cronometro.setText(texto);
    }
    
    
    public static void setBarraProgreso(int value)
    {
        barraProgreso.setValue(value);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Click!");
        if (e.getSource() == cronometroBoton[0])
        {
            if (cronometroCreado == 0)
            {
                temp.start();
                cronometroCreado = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp.getSigaCronometro() == true)
                {
                    temp.setSigaCronometro(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp.setSigaCronometro(true);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == cronometroBoton[1])
        {
            temp.setSigaCronometro(false);
            temp.setTiempo(0);
            barraProgreso.setValue(0);
            MainFrame.setCronometro("Tiempo 0");
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == musicaBoton[0])
        {
        
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == musicaBoton[1])
        {
        
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == tareasBoton)
        {
        
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == calendario)
        {
        
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == trabajadoBoton)
        {
        
        }
    }
}
```

And the other class is:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Temporizador extends Thread{
    
    boolean sigaCronometro = true;
    boolean exit = true;
    long tiempo = 0;
    long tiempoTotal;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date;
        
        public Temporizador(long tiempoTotal)
        {
            this.exit = true;
            this.tiempo = 0;
            this.tiempoTotal = tiempoTotal;
        }
        //Getters y setters
        public boolean getSigaCronometro()
        {
            return this.sigaCronometro;
        }
        
        public void setSigaCronometro(boolean bool)
        {
            this.sigaCronometro = bool;
        }
        
        public boolean getExit()
        {
            return this.exit;
        }
        
        public void setExit(boolean bool)
        {
            this.exit = bool;
        }
        
        public long getTiempo()
        {
            return this.tiempo;
        }
        
        public void setTiempo(long num)
        {
            this.tiempo = num;
        }
        
        private int CalcularPorCiento(long tiempoTranscurrido, long tiempoTotal)
        {
                float porcentaje  =(float)tiempo/(float)tiempoTotal*100;
                System.out.println("El tiempo transcurrido es: " + tiempo);
                System.out.println("El porcentaje que representa es " + porcentaje + " del tiempo" + tiempoTotal);
                return (int)porcentaje*10;
        }
        
    public void  run()
    {
        while(exit == true)
            {
                System.out.println(tiempo);
                while (sigaCronometro)
                {
                   date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Temporizador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    if (sigaCronometro == true)
                    {
                    tiempo+= 1;
                    }
                    if(tiempoTotal <= tiempo)
                    {
                        sigaCronometro = false;
                    }
                    System.out.println(tiempo);
                    MainFrame.setCronometro("Tiempo " + String.valueOf(tiempo));
                    MainFrame.setBarraProgreso(CalcularPorCiento(tiempo, tiempoTotal));
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: *subPaneles[row][column].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));* - don't use a transparent background. Instead use the `setOpaque(false)` method on the component. If you need semi-transparency then check out: [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/)

Comment: You should make the container JFrame visible only at the end, i.e. after all the components are added. I see that you call creacionJFrame(); at the beginning that creates the frame and also calls setSize and setVisible. Try moving setVisible out of it and call it at the end. For example, it should be the last line in //Fin del constructor

Comment: For your 2nd problem where the UI gets messed up once you click on a button: I am not sure but it could be because you perform the operations in a separate Thread. Swing expects all UI operations to be performed in one thread i.e. the UI Thread itself and you should perform your UI actions in the same. 
Try avoiding the new thread altogether and see if it works. You may call the run() method directly by calling temp.run(); instead of temp.start();

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem too

solution:
set opaque of panels to false

inside creacionSubPaneles method add this line

```
    subPaneles[row][column].setOpaque(false);
```

and inside creacionSubSubPaneles method add this line

```
    subSubPaneles[row][column].setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).